# How do I use textbox controls in VB class?

Tags: vb.net, class, oop, controls

I am trying to create an EmployeeID in an 'employee' class using a method. But the ID needs to be able to extract a letter from the 'firstname' textbox in the main design form and then use that to create a unique ID. But I'm unable to call/use any form controls in any of the classes, as they only work on main form. How do I pass the controls to the class so I can do this inside the 'employee' class method instead of the main form?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: No, the ID does not need to extract anything from textboxes. You must give it the contents of the textbox, by passing said contents as an [argument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/procedure-parameters-and-arguments) to that method.

Comment: You are more likely to receive an answer if you provide some code. Edit your question to include the class and the method in the form that calls the this Id method.

Comment: I an guessing that this employee info will be saved to a database. Why don't you let the database provide the ID with an auto-number field (identity field).

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is the wrong way to approach this.  However, it *is* possible to access a form's controls from a class.  You can do this either by accessing open forms (assuming it's open) or passing the textbox as an argument.

**Form:**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim EmployeeA As New ClassEmployee
    Dim EmployeeAID = EmployeeA.GetEmployeeIDFromOpenForm()
    MsgBox("Open Form: " & EmployeeAID)

    MsgBox("Passing Control: " & EmployeeA.GetEmployeeIDFromControl(TxtFirstName))

End Sub
```

**Class:**

```
Public Class ClassEmployee
    Public Function GetEmployeeIDFromOpenForm()
        Dim FirstNameText = Application.OpenForms.Item("Form1").Controls.Find("TxtFirstName", True).SingleOrDefault().Text
        Return FirstNameText
    End Function

    Public Function GetEmployeeIDFromControl(FirstNameTextBox As TextBox)
        Return FirstNameTextBox.Text
    End Function
End Class
```